# Testing Form Submit

Tags: html

I'm setting up a FORM and need to test it without processing the php... how do I make the submit bottom take me to the next padro

```
<form action="test.html" method="POST" id="acct_access">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Define `test` in this situation; what are you testing, that HTML works correctly? This seems almost silly.

Comment: @Tejs How is it silly, it makes perfect since. Instead of processing the process.php I want to go to skip that and go directly to access.html (aka test.html) its for demo reason.

Comment: then simply change your `action` to point to access.html.

Comment: @saluce +1, and I'd like to point out this is no longer a test, but a complete change of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to make some client-side validation (hope I get the question correctly) you need the onsubmit event of the form to be extended:

HTML

```
<form action="test.html" method="POST" id="acct_access" onsubmit="validateForm();">
    ...
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm () {
    //do your validation here

    //you need to return 'true' if everything is valid
    //or 'false' if something went wrong - this will not make the POST call
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `action` to point to the new file.

```
<form action="access.html" method="POST" id="acct_access">
...
</form>
```

Optionally, in the php file, write some short bypass code that will send the user on to the follow-up page.

```
<?php
    header( 'Location: access.html' ) ;
?>
```